# C4labs cloudlet case, 8 x PI 4s, Netgear GC108PP, any chance for PoE?

Tags: pi-4, hat, poe

As a newbie but a Linux oldie I did a fatal error by not documenting myself in advance that I need a HAT for PoE.
I bought basically the C4labs cloudlet case, installed 8 x PI 4s in it.
I got the Netgear GC108PP switch (126W power budget) for PoE.
Then surprise..for PoE I need a hat.
Is there any compact one that does not overheat ... so far google and amazons searches only found rather thick ones height wise which would not fit with that case.
Am left now with wondering:

- is there such a hat
- if not is there any other case I could use? which?
- having 8 x power supplies? but then it looks ugly
- any other solutions?

I'm thinking a compact and not overheating PoE hat would not be so easy to find, right?
What about another case that would go well with this setup?

Thank you and sorry that I messed it up.

Comment: define "compact" ... what is your limit

Comment: You put 8 Pi4s into the same case? And that case does not have a power supply of its own?